# monax command not found on windows

Tags: node.js, docker, blockchain

I am trying to install and configure Monax working on windows from this link: https://monax.io/docs/getting-started/ but for some reason when I type monax in command line is not recognized from git bash nor cmd.

I would like to run this command **monax init** to download few docker images.

I have installed Docker Tool and downloaded Monax binary, but i dont know where do I put these binary.

> Install Docker, Docker Machine, and VirtualBox by downloading the Docker Toolbox and Monax binary from the Release page. Make sure you put the binary under one of the paths in your %PATH% variable.

The last statement I am having problem understanding **Make sure you put the binary under one of the paths in your %PATH% variable.**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Start the Command Prompt window (cmd).
Type 
    `echo %PATH%`
or
    `PATH`
at the prompt. It will show you all the directories in your path, separated by semicolons.
You might need to add a directory to your path to put the files in if you only see Windows system directories in your path.